# Opencv throwing dll error when trying to open image using cv::imshow c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, compiler-errors

So i'm trying to make opencv open a image i have saved on my computer and display it in a window. But my visual studio compiler keeps throwing this excpetion:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF80A2012DB (vcruntime140.dll) in Pixel_analisys.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000021037BD4000.

I have tried to change the file location, double checked the linker if the libraries was linked.
However using the `cv:haveImageReader()` with the same file path it says it is not accesable/not permissions to access it, i have double checked the file location and checked if it is locked in any way and still cant figure this out.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
using namespace std;
cv::Mat a;

int main()
{
    a = cv::imread("C:\\Users\\simuls26\\Desktop\\dog.jpg");
    cv::imshow("dog", a);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my callstack:

> vcruntime140.dll!memcpy_repmovs() Line 40   Unknown
> [Inline Frame] msvcp140.dll!std::_Char_traits<char,int>::copy(char * const) Line 64 C++
> msvcp140.dll!std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits>::xsputn(const char * _Ptr, __int64 _Count) Line 345  C++
> opencv_world455.dll!std::_Insert_string<char,struct std::char_traits,unsigned __int64>(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits > &,char const * const,unsigned __int64)   C++
> opencv_world455.dll!std::allocator<struct cv::Ptr >::deallocate(struct cv::Ptr * const,unsigned __int64)    C++
> opencv_world455.dll!cv::imread(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,int) C++
> opencv_world455.dll!cv::imread(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,int) C++
> Pixel_analisys.exe!main() Line 14   C++
> [External Code]

EDIT: I have fixed the .dll compiler issue by using the visual studio 2015 toolset instead of the 2022 toolset. However now my program wont open my picture. My code is still the same and i have trippled checked my file path. the console output i'm getting are as following

> [ WARN:0@0.056] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('

> failed to open img.jpg

Comment: First of all, provide OpenCV version that you're having the problem with.
Secondly, have you done anything else with this OpenCV version before? I'm just trying to be sure that whether it's `cv::imread` related or not. If you have not, be sure that there's no compiler version mismatch with the static and dynamic libraries.

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev i'm using opencv 4.5.5. Also this is the first time i have used opencv since i just installed it and got it setup. How might i go about checking the compiler versions of them?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio you're using?

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev i'm using visual studio 2022. Figured out that it might have been because of the 2022 toolset so i installed the 2015 one and it stopped throwing the exception. However now my program still wont read the file

Comment: Please, don't forget to provide necessary information when you ask a question.
As for your problem, can you share the current output? (Edit your question, since comment section is not a chatroom)

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev this i my current console output when running my debug 
>[ WARN:0@0.056] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239)
 cv::findDecoder imread_('failed to open img.jpg

Comment: I see that the compiler trys to find necessary libraries in vc15. Try to download OpenCV version that meets your demands. 

vc15 symbolizes the compiler packaged with Visual Studio 2017. Since, you're using VS 2022,  it seems perfectly normal to get errors.

Comment: Thanks, can i get around this by downloading the visual studio 2017 toolset and using that instead?

Comment: You don't have to use Visual Studio 2017 especially. You can either use 2019 or 2022. Since I'm not using Visual Studio 2022 for now, I can't exactly say anything about it. But as already I said, you can use OpenCV 4.5.5 with Visual Studio 2019 without any problem. I answered this question in detail below. If it does not solve your problem, feel free to ask anytime. Otherwise, don't forget to check the answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC is a compiler that Microsoft Visual Studio IDE uses.
Your output log clearly shows that there is a mismatch in the OpenCV library and MSVC version you are using. Make sure the library you have installed is compatible with your compiler. [Microsoft Visual C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B)

As for OpenCV, if you don't build OpenCV yourself(It means, you'll use pre-built binaries), again, make sure that the libraries are inside the `opencvdir/x64/vc16`(vc16:The compiler packaged with Visual Studio 2019). If you are using a higher version of that library, the folder name will already lead you.